# How to change MVC 4 app from passive to active authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wif, claims-based-identity, ws-trust

I have an MVC 4 app setup to redirect to a passive STS site. I don't fully understand all the voodoo that WIF is doing to populate the ClaimsPrincipal on the thread when it returns from the redirect.

We now want to change it to an active STS. Based on small snippets I've picked up from blogs, it looks like what I need to do is use some sort of WSTrustClient to hit the STS' WSTrust endpoint. But using the WSTrust client from Thinktecture.IdentityModel, it looks like that returns a SecurityToken object. I don't see how this is all supposed to be wired up together so that I get the ClaimsPrincipal.

Can anyone give me a shove in the right direction?

Comment: Why would you do that? The Passive profile is what you are supposed to be using for web sites. Active profile is used for "client apps" that proactively request a token from an STS.

Maybe you could expand on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Because he wants the login form to be in the RP and not in the STS. You can do that (and I will answer your question in the idsrv forum). But you will lose SSO of course.

Comment: That's correct, we want the login form to be adjacent to our registration form on the site. I don't see why we lose SSO :-(  Is the idsrv forum the same as the Issues page on Github?

Comment: How would you describe the Login page from Stackoverflow? Doesn't that look like 1 active option (the StackExchange login option) and 3 passive options (Google, Facebook, Yahoo)...?

Answer (score 0):

See here:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/blob/master/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/Extensions/SecurityTokens.cs

Especially the ToClaimsPrincipal() extension method.